# Is it possible to debug a vue app with Visual Studio 2022

Tags: .net, visual-studio, vue.js, asp.net-core, .net-core

I installed Visual Studio 2022 and used the following tutorial to create an app with a vue frontend (javascript or typescript) and a .net core 6 backend.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/tutorial-asp-net-core-with-vue?view=vs-2022

I can start and debug both my projects at once. However, if I set a breakpoint in the frontend javascript code of a component the breakpoint is not hit.

[image: debug_app]

I already enabled script debugging

[image: debug_menu]

Debugging inside DevTools is of course possible. Is it possible to debug the app inside Visual Studio?

Comment: check if you have some UseAuthentication code and if like this:  if (!env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseAuthentication();
                app.UseAuthorization();
            }

Comment: @Oleg I don't think is is an issue with the backend. I can debug javascript code from `*.js` functions in my vue project. Breakpoints inside the `<script>` tag in my `SomeView.vue`  or `SomeComponent.vue` files are unbound.